# How do you remap a share to a different drive?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to write a start up script to take an mapped drive, change the drive letter, then put a different share on the original drive. How can this be done?

Comment: Check out the answer to this question as it might help you in capturing the drive path prior to the delete command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840677/how-can-i-get-a-drive-list-from-a-batch-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.

If for example the existing drive is X: and has \server1\shareA on it and you wanted to remap X: to Y:you could do it with a batch script.

```
net use x: /delete
net use y: \\server1\shareA
```

If you need to pass credentials you'd have to add the username (and possibly the password if you want it to run totally automated.  Note that it's a bad idea to do this with privileged accounts and there are way smarter ways.  But for a quick change over this will do it

```
net use x: /delete
net use y: \\server1\shareA <password> /user:<username>
```

If you don't include the password it will prompt.   You can save this in a .bat file and it will run just fine.

**EDITED TO ADD more complete solution**

So you want to take a drive mapping X: change it to Y: and then connect X: to the new share \server1\newshare?  Here you go.  You can of course still pass credentials if necessary.

```
for /F "skip=1 tokens=3" %%i IN ('net use x:') = DO (
        set OLDSHARE=%%i
        goto :DONE
        )
:DONE

net use x: /delete
net use y: %oldshare%
net use x: \\server1\newshare
```

The `for` loop parses out the existing share path for the drive letter you want to change.  Then you disconnect it from x: reconnect it to y: and then connect the new thing to x: all in quick succession.

Comment: Is it possible to pick up the location of the existing share before deleting it?

Comment: You mean determine it from the script?  Possibly with a bit of fancy parsing.  net use with no arguments returns all the mapped network shares.  Net use with only the drive letter returns information including the remote name.

Comment: I edited my answer above.  Hopefully this is what you want.  It's sort of quick and dirty but it works.

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to figure out what question you answered with "Absolutely". ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [NET USE](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true) command.

You will need to delete the current mapping, then remap with the desired drive letters and shares.

Answer (score 1):

```
net use X: /DELETE
net use X: \\newshare
```

Where `X:` is the drive letter you want to map and `\\newshare` is the location of the new share you want mapped